# How to embed & execute javascript into html?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

index.html

```
<script>
function check() {
        var id = $('input[name=id]').val();
        $("#result").load("/ajax.php", {id:id});        
}
</script>

<input type="text" size="3" name="id"><br />
<button onclick="check();">Pay</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
$id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
//some validations and SQL executions
echo "<script language=JavaScript src='https://*****/index.php?id=$id&invoice=$invoice&sum=$sum.......etc'></script>";
```

I try to form javascript in php file and embed it into div with `id="result"`.
I've used `get`, `load`, `ajax`, `createElement` methods but the script doesn't execute.

Comment: shouldn't your script tag contain valid js file..., you seem to use php file as source of script tag ..?

Comment: To be honest what you do is a bit strange. But if you want to load script by URL to loaded document, you do not have to send whole <script> tag by ajax. Just send URL and generate <script> tag on client side.

Answer (score 1):

try this..
`$('#result').load('ajax.php');`

Comment: I need to send POST data to PHP script

Comment: @user1312750 http://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method - `jQuery.load` supports sending data as POST.

Answer (score 1):

In your php file ajax.php include the header.

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

And in index.html add type=”text/javascript” to the script tag.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
        function check() {
           var id = $('input[name=id]').val();
           $("#result").load("/ajax.php", {id:id});        
         }
   </script>
```

Comment: Since ajax.php returns HTML (<script ...) sending text/javascript content type makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You must load script as real script element. DOM conversion of `"<script>/*...*/</script>"` may fail in this case. This is done via standart DOM `document.createElement` function.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = path;
```

Other way is to download the script via AJAX and then **eval** it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
"<script language=JavaScript src='https://*****/index.php?id="'.$id.'"&invoice="'.$invoice.'"&sum="'.$sum.'".......etc'></script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you load directly the script URL using AJAX?
ajax.php only should return path to the script:

```
 $id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
 //some validations and SQL executions
 echo "https://*****/index.php?id=$id&invoice=$invoice&sum=$sum.......etc";
```

Besides that all HTML element attributes should be enclosed with quotes or apostrohpes.

Then you should load this url in javascript and generate script element here:

```
   function loadScript(url,appendTo) {
     var script = document.createElement("script")
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.src = url;
     if(typeof appendTo.appendChild == "function")     //Chceking if we can append script to given element
       appendTo.appendChild(script); 
     else
       document.body.appendChild(script)       //This will not work in old IE, where document.body is not defined. 
   }
```

You call this function with script url and optional target element (where  will be put in) as parameters.
Like this:

```
  $.get("ajax.php",{param1:"value"},function(scriptUrl) {loadScript(scriptUrl, document.getElementById("result");})
```